# jQuery's fancybox pack unpacked

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

Does anyone knows where can i find the unpack version of the `Jquery.fancybox-x.x.x.pack`?
I did fixed by hand the code indentation to tried to understand it better, but still, is a little hard...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://fancybox.googlegroups.com/web/jquery.fancybox.js?gda=oj1XrkQAAADH0vN5bZ7mMHrrdnkUvV076qWkgAvSo206aFLMIpw3cHOxyMt2jAWI1o446OCwscpV6u9SiETdg0Q2ffAyHU-dzc4BZkLnSFWX59nr5BxGqA) It's on their google code page

Answer (score 2):

From their website, it appears to be right there in their download.

http://fancybox.net/